# How to capture my screen video stream?

Tags: kernel, xorg

I try to capture the output of my gpu, the video flux of my desktop, to stream it on another computer. I'm working on a project like a remote control terminal so I can't have any latency.

I have already tested with VLC and lots of other programs of streaming but I can't send the raw flux, forcing to use a codec, which generates really too much of latency.

Answer (score 0):

If external hardware is an option, find a good USB HDMI capture device.  The good ones will present themselves as a UVC webcam-like device, making it really easy to figure out how to display the incoming video stream.

Software-wise, I've gotten the best results from GStreamer.  jpeg encoding over RTP will give a good compromise of quality vs. latency at 1080p.  Something like H.263 will be blazing fast but with limited quality at that resolution.  Sending raw video will be the best at lower resolutions where bandwidth is not an issue.  1Gb/s LAN will serve you well.

Comment: I have found the problem..! I use the framebuffer of my gpu in /dev/fb0 with mplayer. I change the output video to fbdev1 (video framebuffer device).

Comment: It's so funny ! With that we can read videos in tty :) Graphical interface it's useless for me now !

Comment: That's cool, you might be interested in [libcaca](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca) which has plugins for many media players.